# Finding the likelihood of joint exponential random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

This is problem 8.27 from *Statistics for Data Analysis, Third Edition* by John Rice (Page 318):
Suppose that certain electronic components have lifetimes that are exponentially distributed:
$f(t|\tau) = \frac{1}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau}$ where $t\gt 0$. Five new components are put on test, the first one fails at 100 days, and no further observations are recorded.

Find the likelihood of $\tau$:

The given answer is: $l(\tau) = \frac{5}{\tau}e^{-500/\tau}$

**But my solution differs, and these are my steps:**

If we assume that the components are i.i.d then:

$$
l(\tau)=f(t_1, ...,t_5)=\prod_{i=1}^{5} f(t_i|\tau)
$$

Now the data we have tells us that the first component fails at $t=100$ days therefore:

$$
f(t_1=100|\tau)=\frac{1}{\tau}e^{-100/t}
$$

What else we know is that the other components have lifetimes greater than $100$ days:

$$
P_{T_2, ...,T_5}(T_2 > 100, ...,T_5 > 100) =  \prod_{i=2}^{5}P(T_i >100) \\
=\prod_{i=1}^{5}(1-F_{T_{i}}(100)) \\
=(1-F_{T_{i}}(100))^4
$$
Therefore to find the density function:
$$
f_{T_2,...,T_5}(100|\tau) = -\frac{d}{dt}[(1-F_{T_{i}}(100))^4] \\
=-\frac{d}{dt}[(1-(1-e^{-100/\tau})^4] \\
=\frac{4}{\tau}e^{-400/\tau}
$$

Thus,
$$
l(\tau) = f_{T_1}(100|\tau)f_{T_2,...,T_5}(100|\tau) \\
= \frac{4}{\tau}e^{-500/\tau}
$$

Where is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: Why did you assume component #1 failed and not components #2 through #5? The given solution suggests that you are only interested in the first time that *any* of the components fail.

Comment: From the question the components seem indistinguishable from one another and are independent and thus my label is arbitrary right?